# What's the best approach to deal with enum flags in web APIs

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, nswag

I have a few flag enums that I use on my web API and, so far, the all I've seen is changing the combined value of the flags being passed as an array.

Is there a way to declare it in a more .NET/C# friendly way? Maybe using `collectionFormat=csv`.

**Edit 1**

Imagine I have this enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Directions
{
    Up = 1,
    Down = 2,
    Left = 4,
    Right = 8,
}
```

And this C# method to be exposed as an API:

```
public class Request
{
    Directions Directions {get; set; }
}

public void SetAvailableDirections(Request request)
{
    // ...
}
```

Because the parameter has multiple values, it should be an `array` but if I can build a swagger specification that has `collectionFormat` set to `csv`, it can be an `array` as far as swagger is concerned and a plain old flags enum in C#/CLR.

Is this possible?

**Edit 2**

Using [Service Stack](http://docs.servicestack.net/swagger-api) it would be (as I've been told by someone that uses it) something like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum Directions
{
    Up = 1,
    Down = 2,
    Left = 4,
    Right = 8,
}

public class Request
{
    [ApiMember(Name = nameof(Directions), AllowMultiple = true, ...)]
    [ApiAllowableValues(nameof(Directions), typeof(Directions))]
    Directions Directions {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example, and make question more specific?

Comment: If you want an array then pass an array and rebuild the final `Directions` value from that array. ie: `public Directions[] Directions { get;set; }` for your client facing model and then have another method or extension method (or something) to return a `Directions` instance based on that.

Comment: @Igor, I really don't know what to answer to your comment.

Comment: 1. If you really do want an array then pass that and assume that every item in that array is a single value. Personally I think its a poor choice and should be avoided. 2. Use the API as is. If the caller wants `Up` and `Left` they pass in `5`, if they want `Right` they pass in `8` if they want everything they pass in `15`.... `Flags` works the same way regardless of the client. I am not sure why or how you or the calling client is having issues with `Flags`.

Comment: See https://github.com/NJsonSchema/NJsonSchema/issues/226